# fscanf inside a do-while not working

Tags: c, loops, do-while, scanf

So, I'm having problem to read a file using a do-while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

FILE* f = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
double i;

do{

fscanf(f, "%lf ", &i);
printf(" %.0lf", i);

} while (fscanf(f, "%lf", &i) != EOF);

return 0;

}
```

The file is ike that:

> 1 2 3 4 5

When i run the program, the output is:

> 1 3 5

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are calling fscanf twice, once in the do-while loop and once in the while test again! You are losing one read this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are discarding the result of every second call to `fscanf`.

In the `while` condition you call `fscanf` and check for `EOF` but you do not use the value of `i`. Then the next statement is back up the top of the loop , doing another `fscanf` which reads the next value (and does not check for error).

Also, you have an infinite loop if the file contains any text which is not a valid `double`.

The loop should be:

```
while ( fscanf(f, "%lf", &i) == 1 )
{
    printf(" %.0f", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
    double i;
    fscanf(f, "%lf ", &i);
    do {
        printf(" %.0lf", i);
    } while (fscanf(f, "%lf", &i) != EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

after `fscanf(f, "%lf ", &i);`,  `f` contains `1`. Now after `fscanf(f, "%lf", &i) != EOF`, `f` contains `2`. You are not printing that `2` and after next `fscanf(f, "%lf ", &i);`, `f` will contain `3`. In short you are calling `fscanf` twice in every loop and `printf` only once.